# Python deleting temporary files on trinket.io

Tags: python

I'm really new to coding sorry if my questions sound stupid. I've created a program and I need it to delete any temporary files created during runtime. 
So far the first error I've stumbled upon is insufficient permissions to delete a folder, hence the try-except for `PermissionError`.Secondly I need to upload this to a trinket.io link to test it and send it to be graded but nothing seems to be deleted there and no permission errors either? Seems like the whole function is getting skipped. Here is what i have so far on the file-deleting function. It keeps only the 4 necessary files...

```
def clear_temps():
    c=os.getcwd()
    d=os.listdir(c)
    for file in d:
        if '.py' in file or '.csv' in file and not file=='mytemp.csv':
            pass
        else:
            if os.path.isdir(file):
                os.path.split(file)
            try:
                os.remove(file)
            except PermissionError:
                pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you wrote should work fine. Try it in a local Python editor to check it for sure.

I have noticed that in trinket when you delete a file the tab is not removed, but if you check in the folder the file is not there.

You can use this code to check out if the file is still there:

```
def clear_temps():
c=os.getcwd()
d=os.listdir(c)
for file in d:
    if '.py' in file or '.csv' in file and not file=='mytemp.csv':
        pass
    else:
        if os.path.isdir(file):
            os.path.split(file)
        try:
            print(os.path.isfile(file)) 
            os.remove(file)
            print(os.path.isfile(file)) 
        except PermissionError:
            pass
```

I added an check if the file exists before and after the remove. 
So in case of an output : `True False` the file in trinket has been really deleted and in case of an `True True` the file is still there.